# If a service is started during docker build, should it be running at runtime?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, docker, debian

I have been working on setting up a self contained rails app in a single container. This means getting both rails and a data persistence service running at the same time in one container. In our case, that means mysql.

However, I ran into multiple issues getting this working, because mysql wasn't running.

During the build step, if I had `RUN mysqld` and then a separate `RUN rake db:create` step, rake would crash, because mysql was down.

So I worked around this by wrapping the two commands into a script. However, at runtime, rails would fail to startup because mysql wasn't running.

My intuition says that if mysql is started during the build, it should be available at runtime, but I did not have that experience. Starting the rails server had to be wrapped in a script with another call to `mysqld`.

Here's the dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby:2.2
RUN mkdir -p $APPDIR
WORKDIR $APPDIR
ADD Gemfile* $APPDIR/
RUN bundle install
RUN apt-get update -qq
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y -qq nodejs mysql-server --no-install-recommends
RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* # */ broken syntax highlighting
COPY . $APPDIR
RUN script/mysql-setup.sh # contents are: mysqld_safe; rake db:create; rake db:migrate
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["script/rails-launcher.sh"] # contents are: mysqld_safe; rails s
```

Do I need to do something differently in the Dockerfile? Why isn't mysql up at runtime?

Comment: There's a line I left out of the dockerfile: `ENV APPDIR /usr/src/app`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My intuition says that if mysql is started during the build, it should be available at runtime

This is incorrect. Docker will start the service for you and perform the subsequent steps you've defined in the same `RUN` command, but then it bundles everything up into an intermediate image for subsequent commands. The image doesn't have a known state of running processes, only whatever is required for startup such as `init.d` scripts.

Your solution would be to [use a server startup script](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-server.html) or continue to invoke `mysqld_safe` as you do in your `CMD` line.

A good idea is to use `supervisord` to maintain all of your services in a non-daemon mode. [Phusion also provides a nice base image](https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker) with a runit initializer script.

Eventually, you'll come to see how the power of Docker lies in how you can actually break MySQL out of your Rails app container and run it in [an entirely different container](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/) linked together.

Comment: I do plan to split the persistence into another container, but I wanted to start with everything self-contained.

Comment: Thank you much for this!

Answer (score 1):

The `RUN` Command is used to configure your image, each time it is called, a new layer is created with the results of run command. So, if you need to configure your database on the image build step, you have 2 solutions: you can call a number of command in a single `RUN` call, like

```
RUN /bin/bash -c  "mysqld_safe" && "rake db:create" && "rake db:migrate"
```

Or via call of single script, as you did.

In both cases, you have to inderstand, that the fact, you runned something during the image build, it'll not run automatcally on the container start up. So, you have to start your database server manually on container start up.